# Connecting Azure SQL Database, from Azure Web Site running PHP 5.5?

Tags: php, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

If you setup an Azure website to run PHP 5.5, the "sqlsrv" extension disappears, presumably because the current release of that extension [doesn't support past PHP 5.4](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/790641/sql-server-driver-for-php-5-5). As you can see from that post, Microsoft has been "working on" an updated sqlsrv extension since July 2013. The [official blog for this extension](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlphp/) hasn't been updated since Oct 2012, and the last post that was [actually about the sqlsrv extension](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlphp/archive/2012/03/23/microsoft-drivers-3-0-1-for-php-for-sql-server-with-php-5-4-support-release.aspx) is from March 2012.

There is an [unofficial version of the sqlsrv extension that supports PHP 5.5](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e1d37219-88a3-46b2-a421-73bfa33fe433/unofficial-php-55-drivers-x86), but you can't install custom PHP extensions on an Azure managed web site.

As far as I can tell, that means you cannot connect to a Azure SQL data from an Azure manage web site, and it doesn't look like Microsoft is in a rush to fix this. I'm just about to give up on using PHP 5.5 + SQL Server on Azure.

However, I'm hoping there is something I'm missing. Is it possible to run a PHP 5.5 app as a managed web site on Azure and connect to SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has now released support for PHP 5.5 and 5.6 connections via their [Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx) PHP extension. Version 3.2 (current as of April 1st, 2015) supports PHP 5.4, 5.5, and 5.6.

As a result, Azure PHP web apps should be able to connect to Microsoft SQL Server "out of the box" without having to install any additional drivers.

Note on Azure terminology change since question was posted: "[Websites is now Web Apps in App Service](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9876439&clcid=0x409)"

Answer (score 2):

You can start with installing the above-mentioned custom PHP extension on Azure Web Site. It is surely supported process and is [well described here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlining/archive/2012/09/17/using-custom-php-extensions-in-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx).

So make your site running with the custom PHP extension while waiting for the official one.

Comment: I didn't realize this was possible, but I'm glad to be wrong about this. Thank you!

Comment: no worries, it still sad that there is no official extension.

Comment: Indeed... hopefully it's really happening, and the project hasn't been abandoned. I admit it concerns  me that the sqlsrv blog hasn't been updated in two years. But at least on the [Microsoft Connect issue page](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/790641/sql-server-driver-for-php-5-5) for this there was a note from MS in June saying that they're working on it.